# Error in editing real time data base rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I had copied exactly as per the details provided in fire base document
[enter link description here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/insecure-rules)
for editing the rules as I received a mail from firebase that my clients will not be able to access data. But what ever I had done I am getting an error like "Error saving rules – Line 4: Expected ',' or '}'.

The code I had copied is shown below

```
{
  "rules": {
    "some_path/${uid}": {
      ".read": true,
      // or ".read": "auth.uid != null" 
      ".write": "request.auth.uid == uid"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried with some other codes in document also, but the result is same.. Will any one tell me what is wrong with this code

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "some_path/${uid}": {
      ".read": //Your Condition,
      ".write": //Your Condition
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I had copied as shown in the firebase document in the link, actually that is supposed to work right?? why that is not working ...

Comment: Which out of 3 you copied?

Comment: I tried with content owner only using this code {
  "rules": {
    "some_path": {
      "$uid": {
        // Allow only authenticated content owners access to their data
        ".read": "request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == $uid"
        ".write": "request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
    and Mixed public and private access as provided in document in https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/insecure-rules

Comment: for relatime data base only

Comment: @sadasivanParameshwaran Did you change `some_path/${uid}` to respective path and tried?

Comment: No I didnt change path . sorry . how to change the path ??

Comment: I am not much familiar with Realtime Database. Maybe see google docs for help

Comment: `".read": if //Your Condition,` The `if` in there is not valid in rules for the Realtime Database. Rules with `if` are only available on Firestore and Storage.

Answer (score 0):

You have the syntax for wildcard rules wrong. The rule with a `$` needs to be in a level of its own.

So:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "some_path": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "request.auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I also added the `$` in the write rule, as you're trying to use the variable named `$uid`. there.